# domain name does not resolve to IP WHM

Tags: whm

I've just set up WHM, I though everything was configured properly and I've uploaded files for one site. I can't get a domain name to resolve to this site.

I try: /scripts/ipcheck --verbose
Which says 'sent email!! Errors found' - but I never get the email, despite my email address being correctly set in Basic Web Host Manager Setup.

How can I correct this so I can see what errors there are? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to search the server logs (in your case email logs). Login via ssh to your WHM server and monitor your email server log by issueing the command bellow:

```
tail -f /var/log/exim_mainlog
```

Then try to execute again the script:

```
/scripts/ipcheck --verbose
```

Please keep in mind that in order to be able to send emails (especially if you send them to yahoo/gmail/outlook.com/hotmail etc) you will need these:

```
- a valid server hostname: host.domain.tld and the proper A record in the DNS zone
- ideally you will also need rDNS for your server's main ip which should be exactly as the server's hostname
- your server's ip should be clean (not blacklisted); you can check if your ip is blacklisted on mxtoolbox
```

If the conditions above are not met then it's quite probably that the emails are not leaving your server and stay in the mail queue. You can also check that in:

```
WHM -> Email -> Mail Queue Manager
```

Comment: Thanks, the emails were in the mail queue. This is what the error says:IP address-related problem detected.

IMPORTANT: Do not ignore this email.

Some or all of these problems can be caused by an incorrect configuration in the /etc/resolv.conf file. Check the file or use the Resolver Configuration Wizard interface in WHM at https://localhost.localdomain.com:2087/scripts/setupresolvconf to verify that everything is correct.

Comment: The nameserver IP addresses shown in /etc/resolv.conf were not correct. I've changed them to the actual namerserver IP addresses and now the domain resolves correctly. Thanks.

Comment: If that's all could you please mark the question as answered?